# Geopandas read geometry from geo_interface as JSON column in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, folium, geopy

I have a `GeoDataFrame` with a geometry column (of polygons) and few other columns used for plotting polygons and their marker popups on the map. I exported this dataframe by using `gdf.__geo_interface__` as a column `geo` and other attributes to a CSV file using `to_csv` on the complete `DataFrame`.

The `geo` column looks like

```
{'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': [{'id': '1', 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {...}}
```

How can I read back from the CSV file and get the `GeoDataFrame` using the CSV? Specifically, how can I create back the original columns (polygons and attributes) that I had in the `GeoDataFrame`?

Comment: Can you please share a little more of the data, e.g., by posting the 4 first rows of the column? if the column is in a dataframe df, do this: ```df.head(4).to_dict()```and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following situation:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
d = {'col1': ['name1', 'name2'], 'geometry': [Point(1, 2), Point(2, 1)]}
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(d, crs="EPSG:4326")
gdf
```

you can define a function that will flatten any `json` by:

```
def flatten_nested_json_df(df):
    df = df.reset_index()
    s = (df.applymap(type) == list).all()
    list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    
    s = (df.applymap(type) == dict).all()
    dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

    
    while len(list_columns) > 0 or len(dict_columns) > 0:
        new_columns = []

        for col in dict_columns:
            horiz_exploded = pd.json_normalize(df[col]).add_prefix(f'{col}.')
            horiz_exploded.index = df.index
            df = pd.concat([df, horiz_exploded], axis=1).drop(columns=[col])
            new_columns.extend(horiz_exploded.columns) # inplace

        for col in list_columns:
            #print(f"exploding: {col}")
            df = df.drop(columns=[col]).join(df[col].explode().to_frame())
            new_columns.append(col)

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == list).all()
        list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == dict).all()
        dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    return df
```

Now, you used `geo = gdf.__geo_interface__`  which returned something like:

```
{'type': 'FeatureCollection',
 'features': [{'id': '0',
   'type': 'Feature',
   'properties': {'col1': 'name1'},
   'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (1.0, 2.0)},
   'bbox': (1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0)},
  {'id': '1',
   'type': 'Feature',
   'properties': {'col1': 'name2'},
   'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (2.0, 1.0)},
   'bbox': (2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0)}],
 'bbox': (1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0)}
```

Note that I called it `geo`. Then, do this:

```
json = json.dumps(geo) 
df = pd.json_normalize(geo)
flatten_nested_json_df(df)
```

Which will give you:

```
index               type                  bbox features.id features.type  \
0      0  FeatureCollection  (1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0)           0       Feature   
0      0  FeatureCollection  (1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0)           1       Feature   

          features.bbox features.properties.col1 features.geometry.type  \
0  (1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0)                    name1                  Point   
0  (2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0)                    name2                  Point   

  features.geometry.coordinates  
0                    (1.0, 2.0)  
0                    (2.0, 1.0)
```

Comment: The `geo` object has the same JSON format as you have shown. Now when I need to read It back into a `GeoDataFrame` from a `csv` file, then do I need to write a function to manually parse the JSON back to the columns of the `DataFrame` or can this be done directly using any function?

Comment: You should be able to do it using any function. Let me know if you struggle with it.

Comment: I meant to ask if I need to use `flatten_nested_json_df` like you have defined or is there any in-built function to convert the `gdf.__geo_interface__` back to the `geopandas.GeoDataFrame`?

Comment: ```flatten_json``` has some build-in function but I created this function because I had to deal with nested columns that I didn't want to have to find the path for. This function deals with ANY type of json with nested fields. So, you never need to worry about how deeply nested it is.

Comment: Don't forget to check it as the accepted answer if this solves your problem. Happy coding!

Comment: I am facing an issue in calling `flatten_nested_json_df`. The `geo` object is currently stored as a column of a different Dataframe, for example it is read in as `geo = mydf.iloc[0]['geo']`. In this case `geo` is a `str` so I am not able to call your function which expects a `df` and if I call `json.dumps` on it gives the error `'str' object has no attribute 'dumps'`. Any suggestion to get around this?

Comment: Have you tried ```json = json.dumps(geo) 
df = pd.json_normalize(geo)
flatten_nested_json_df(df)```` or something like that?

Comment: Using `pd.json_normalize(geo)` gives 'NotImplementedError: ' while `json.dumps(geo)` gives 'str' object has no attribute 'dumps'
The issue seems to be that `geo` is now of type `str` when I have read it from a dataframe using `iloc`

Comment: What about? ```json_object = json.loads(geo)```, then ```json = json.dumps(geo) ``` and so on?

Comment: An issue I am facing is that in the key `"coordinates": (((-1.745, 4.63), (-11.9, 43.5), (-26.741, 43.669), (-36.75, 11.11)), )` I am getting an extra `,` in the end, can I handle that explicitly before calling `json.dumps`, since it gives error `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column XX`